# Could not able to find root directory (Company Home) in alfresco

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

I am searching "/Company Home" root directory from the repository. I did the following way
CmisObject object = session.getObjectByPath(objectPath, OperationContext)
where objectPath is="/Company Home/Tests-folder"
but after executing above code got the following exception:

> org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException:
>   Object not found: /Company Home/Tests-folder at
>   org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.getObjectByPath(AlfrescoCmisServiceImpl.java:2077)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor572.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor$1.execute(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:79)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:457)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionInterceptor.invoke(RetryingTransactionInterceptor.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisStreamInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisStreamInterceptor.java:72)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisServiceInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisServiceInterceptor.java:101)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.alfresco.opencmis.AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.invoke(AlfrescoCmisExceptionInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy328.getObjectByPath(Unknown Source)

I searched in the repository using node UUID like 
session.getObject("2dc70dba-1cd1-4b36-84ff-ee4f17e981cb").getName(); and it returns the "Company Home" directory name. I would like to know why it is not searching directory "Company Home" using 
session.getObjectByPath("/Company Home/Tests-folder") method?
But I can access the "/Tests-folder".

Comment: Try with a qname path instead?

Comment: @Gagravarr I have tried with "/app:company_home"  but its not working

Comment: try to move from the root and the root is `"/"` and tell me what's happenning

Comment: @yagami thanks for your reply. But I am new in Alfresco so don't know how to move Company Home folder from "/" root? and as per my knowledge Company Home is default folder right? So how can I move this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Company Home is the root of your repository. So if Tests-folder lives in the root, the correct way to use getObjectByPath would be session.getObjectByPath("/Tests-folder").

Comment: thanks. but my question is why i am not getting the CmisObject for "/Company Home" directory using seesion.getObjectByPath();

Comment: The reason is that "/Company Home" is not a valid path. The valid path for Company Home is "/" so your call should be session.getObjectByPath('/');

Comment: thanks Jeff. So I am using Alfresco version 5.1 in that the "Company Home" is not available right? But on client side ui I am able to see  Company Home under "/". how this possible that in server side not able to access Company Home directory.

Comment: There is no such thing as the Company Home directory. There is a root directory and its name is "Company Home", but you do not use "Company Home" when getting the root directory by path. When you do a getObjectByPath("/") what comes back will be the exact same object as the folder you see in the UI which is labeled "Company Home".

Comment: Thank you Jeff this information is very heplful for me.

Comment: Hi Jeff, do you have any reference link or document so I can read more about CMIS. Actually I need to understand that why it can't recognized the Company Home directory from repository.I am using Alfresco 5.1 version.